# When to include an index (automated heuristic)

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I have a piece of software which takes in a database, and uses it to produce graphs based on what the user wants (primarily queries of the form `SELECT AVG(<input1>) AS x, AVG(<intput2>) as y FROM <input3> WHERE <key> IN (<vals..> AND ...`).  This works nicely.

I have a simple script that is passed a (often large) number of files, each describing a row

```
name=foo
x=12
y=23.4
....... etc.......
```

The script goes through each file, saving the variable names, and an `INSERT` query for each.  It then loads the variable names, `sort | uniq`'s them, and makes a `CREATE TABLE` statement out of them (sqlite, amusingly enough, is ok with having all columns be `NUMERIC`, even if they actually end up containing text data).  Once this is done, it then executes the `INSERTS` (in a single transaction, otherwise it would take ages).

To improve performance, I added an basic index on each row.  However, this increases database size somewhat significantly, and only provides a moderate improvement.

Data comes in three basic types:

1. single value, indicating things like program version, etc.
2. a few values (<10), indicating things like input parameters used
3. many values (>1000), primarily output data.

The first type obviously shouldn't need an index, since it will never be sorted upon.
The second type should have an index, because it will commonly be filtered by.
The third type probably shouldn't need an index, because it will be used in output.
It would be annoying to determine which type a particular value is before it is put in the database, but it is possible.

My question is twofold:

1. Is there some hidden cost to extraneous indexes, beyond the size increase that I have seen?
2. Is there a better way to index for filtration queries of the form `WHERE foo IN (5) AND bar IN (12,14,15)`?  Note that I don't know which columns the user will pick, beyond the that it will be a type 2 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the relevant documentation:
[Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html);
[Query Optimizer Overview](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html);
[EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

The most important thing for optimizing queries is avoiding I/O, so tables with less than ten rows should not be indexed because all the data fits into a single page anyway, so having an index would just force SQLite to read another page for the index.

Indexes are important when you are looking up records in a big table.

1. Extraneous indexes make table updates slower, because each index needs to be updated as well.
2. SQLite can use at most one index per table in a query.
   This particular query could be optimized best by having a single index on the two columns `foo` and `bar`.
   However, creating such indexes for all possible combinations of lookup columns is most likely not worth the effort.
   If the queries are generated dynamically, the best idea probably is to create one index for each column that has good selectivity, and rely on SQLite to pick the best one.

And don't forget to run [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html).

Comment: What I was looking for.  As a side note, if you're wondering how many indices are required to cover any subset of n columns, under the sqlite rules (multi-column indices are used from the left, so `foo,bar` can be used from a `foo,bar,baz` index, but not a `foo, baz, bar` index), it ends up being n!/((n/2)!)^2 for even n, and n!/(((n-1)/2)!((n+1)/2)!) for odd n. That is, 1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 20, 35, 70, 126, 252...  This is really only vaguely reasonable for 5-6 columns (10 and 20 indices, respectively).